# Eloquent relationship unwanted repetition of the relation name in json output

Tags: json, laravel, eloquent

I am performing a relationship in eloquent and I am not getting the Json I want. I am using something like this:

```
 return User::with('permissao.telaSistema')->find(26);
```

Is producing  the following json:

```
 {
    "id" : 1000,
    "total_operadores": null,
    "permissao": [
        {
            "tela_sistema": [
                {
                    "id": 7,
                    "nome_tela": "generic mkt"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "tela_sistema": [
                {
                    "id": 6,
                    "nome_tela": "generic mkt2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

wouldn't it be wiser to generate something like this:

```
{
"id": 1000,
"total_operadores": null,
"permissao": [
    {
        "tela_sistema": [
            {
                "id": 7,
                "nome_tela": "generic mkt"
            },

            {
                "id": 6,
                "nome_tela": "generic mkt 2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

I wonder if it is not my relationship declaration on the model that are wrong. Here is my models.

```
class User {
    public function permissao(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Permissao', 'operador_id', 'id');
    }
```

}

Permissao class

```
Class Permissao
  {
    public function user() {

        return $this->belongsToOne('App\User', 'id', 'operador_id');

    }

    public function telaSistema() {

        return $this->hasOne('App\TelaSistema', 'id', 'tela_id');

    }

}
```

Telas sistema class

```
TelaSistema class
 {
    public function permissao()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Permissao', 'id', 'tela_id');
    }
}
```

Here is the structure of the tables.

```
 User                      Permissao                    Tela_sistema
    id  (one) -> (many)     operador_id         
                              tela_id     (many) -> (one)        id
```

Comment: Please add your Model code as well

Comment: No it makes sense to return it like this as each `permissao` is supposed to have it's own properties (e.g. id). In your case, they are hidden from the JSON, so you could modify the structure a little bit to match your needs but you should keep it this way in case later your permissao has properties to be returned as well.

Answer (score 0):

I did it! I used Has Many Through.

```
     public function telaSistema()
     {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\TelaSistema', 'App\Permissao', 'operador_id', 'id', 'id' ,'tela_id');
     }
```

I don't know if I supplied the arguments correctly but apparently it worked.

```
 {
    "id" : 1000,
    "total_operadores": null,

    "tela_sistema": [
        {
            "id": 7,
            "nome_tela": "generic mkt",
            "operador_id": 26
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "nome_tela": "generic mkt2",
            "operador_id": 26
        }
    ]
}
```